# Why did Michael and Phyllis from The Office not roast each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

In the S05E14 Stress Relief, Michael organizes a roast of himself to release some stress in the office. Everybody takes part in the roast and tries their best to embarrass Michael except Phyllis, who doesn't take part in the roast. I wonder why? I mean, they are not that good friends for Phyllis NOT to roast him like everyone else.

In return, when Michael roasts everyone in the office, he does not roast Phyllis. Not a single word. Is this because Phyllis did not say anything to him?

Additionally, Darryl did roast him but Michael did not give a reply to Darryl either. I wonder why?

Comment: Michael and Pyllis know each other from a long time ago (they were school mates) and might have a lot of info on each other. They might not want to mess with each other. Another reason could be that Michael is afraid of Bob Vance Vance Refrigeration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Everybody takes part in the roast, tries their best to embarrass Michael except Phyllis, who doesn't take part in the roast. I wonder why?

---

It's really not Phyllis's personality to openly roast someone. In fact, I can only recall two instances of Phyllis blatantly insulting Michael throughout the entire series --

One, when Michael interviews for corporate (S03E23),

> PHYLLIS: I think it's gonna be Michael.
> OSCAR: Do you really think he's qualified for that job?
> PHYLLIS: No, but he wasn't qualified for the job he has now and he got that one.

and two, when Michael gets counseling from Toby (S07E02):

> PHYLLIS: I'm glad Michael's getting help. He has a lot of issues, and he's stupid.

It is worth noting though that when Michael announces the roast to the office, Phyllis does immediately start writing down material for the roast, however, once they actually get to the roast Phyllis doesn't have any papers/note cards at the table with her (whereas everyone else who roasted Michael did).

If I had to guess, I'd say that Phyllis *did* intend on roasting Michael but then **Bob Vance talked her out of it**.

---

> Additionally, Darryl Did roast him but Michael did not give a reply to Darryl either. I wonder why (?)

Simple!, because Darryl wasn't in the office at the time of Michael roasting everyone. Also, Michael is afraid of Darryl so I doubt he would have said anything anyway.

Comment: Yes but Phyllis isn't really that mallow or soft heart. She insults Pam on multiple occasions. Shouts at Ryan when he is talking to Dwight's client and Shouts on Dwight (Although that was entirely Dwight's fault to throw Phyllis 5 miles off office).
So I don't think Phyllis did not want to roast Michael.. I wonder why she could not just get up and say what she wrote about him

Comment: Perhaps Phyllis gave everyone else the material?  I haven't seen this but if she started writing things down, then ends up without any... Just a passing random thought.

Comment: @Dave I also considered that however the material each person said was pretty specific to their own personality and the experience(s) they've had with Michael.

Comment: @FaizanShah Phyllis seems more like the "gossip and talk trash behind your back" type of character.  It seems very rare that she offers up insults or negativity about someone to their face.

Comment: @Shahsays: Phyllis uses passive aggressive comments or veiled insults. Roasting is quite the opposite, very straightforward and to the point. It makes sense for her to not take to a stage like that, given her soft-spoken (though not always kind) nature.